# ffmpeg video concate not working when one video is generated from a single image

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

what I am doing is generating a video of 5 secs from a single image using FFmpeg.

for that I'm using the following command:

> -loop 1 -i image.jpg -c:v libx264 -t 5 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 25 -s 1280x720 Out.mp4.

Now I want to concatenate this video with another one.

I am able to do this for other videos with the following command

> -y -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -strict experimental -filter_complex [0:v]scale=1280x720,setsar=1:1[v0][1:v]scale=1280x720,setsar=1:1[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a]
>   concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 -s 1280x720 -r 30 vcodec
>   mpeg4 -b 2097k output.mp4

But when I join the video generated from the image, the videos do not join as the second input does not have an audio because it is generated from the image.So is there any way to join these two videos using `-filter_complex` in FFmpeg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your image to video to include a silent audio track:

```
-loop 1 -i image.jpg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -c:v libx264 -t 5 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 25 -s 1280x720 Out.mp4.
```

Concat filter requires paired inputs.

Comment: I also want to add an image overlay over this video .Can you help me please?

Comment: Over the image video, or the combined videos?

Comment: over the image video

Comment: `-loop 1 -i image.jpg -i overlay.jpg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -filter_complex overlay -c:v libx264 -t 5 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 25 -s 1280x720 Out.mp4.`

Comment: The overlaid image is very small but.Is there a way to increase the width and height of the overlaid image??